# java object oriented programming

Tags: java, arrays, methods

first off im new here. and i dont know if some peoples will be able to help me but i hope somebody can help me.
the thing is we will have an java exam about object oriented programming , methods and classes and i wasnt there when we had that  and i just received a image of the exam and i have = 0 knowledge about java. i can just do some basic java code but i never looked into that new stuff. 
what we will have on the exam is 2 tasks . i will post the exam down below .

```
Task 1.
------------------------------
Class STUDENT

classvariable (private)
lastname, firstname, gender, birthyear  of student

constructor 
the 4 values will be added to the constructor.the values in the  Constructor will be assigned to the class variables.

method toString()
the data from the students (the 4 class variables) will be connected to string and stored in a variable .
Form:
Lastname: Muster
Firstname: Max
Birthyear : 1997
Gender: Male
This Variable will be returned by the Mehod.

Method outputStudentdata()
The string from the method toString() will print out.


Task 2.
-------------------------------
Class SCHOOLCLASS

Classvariable
A suitable container to store a school class with an indefinite number of students (static, Array, ArrayList ...)

Method outputClasslist()
for every student in the classroom the index number of the container and the 4 properties surname, first name, year and Gender will be output (use the method outputStudentdata() from the STUDENT Class!)

Method DeleteStudent()
You can enter the index number of the Student you'd like to delete and the student is then deleted from the container (See Default Output)

Method Classsize()
the Classsize (amount of student in  Class) is output. (See Default Output)

Method setStudent()
you can enter the last name, first name, gender and the birthyear of the new student(See Default Output)
a new object of class student will be created.
The method returns the object of the class students back.

Method Main()
Following menu will show up:

What Would you like to do?
0 > Exit
1 > Create new Student and add to Schoolclass
2 > Delete Student from Schoolclass
3 > Show Classlist
4 > Show Classsize
Enter your choice : 


You can enter your choice.
your choice will then be executed.
If you enter a not valid number(not 0 - 4), a Errormsg will appear.
The Programm will Loop until the numeric code 0 was choosen.
A message appears to Adoption

It is executed, what You have chosen. Enter a not valid number (not 0-4), an error message appears, the program is repeated until the numeric code when choosing 0 A message appears to Adoption.
```

i hope somebody can explain me how this works 
thanks in advance

and please  dont think i want to be spoonfeeded. 
im here to learn how to do it.
i dont want to fail on this exam

Comment: This is not a good question for this site (in fact there is no question at all), and will be downvoted and most likely closed. Please read the help centre for information on what constitutes a good question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reticulated Spine and Gamedroids are correct in that this is not a question suitable for stack overflow. A simple google search turns up many, many resources available to use.

To get you started, [this tutorial](http://www.asgteach.com/blog/?p=559) should help you with getters, setters, and toString, and you should be able to use google to figure out the rest of your assignment.